# Plot Individual Vectors Online

Tags: vectors, math-software, visualization

I'm looking to plot individual vectors (not a field) for an equilibrium lab using some type of free online site or tool. I've googled for a while and found nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) can be run online at [sagenb.org](http://sagenb.org/); an account can be created in no time with existing OpenID. It draws vectors with a simple command

```
arrow((0,1), (2,3))
```

where (0,1) is the initial point and (2,3) is the terminal point. Several arrows can be drawn at once:

```
arrow((0,1), (2,3)) + arrow((2,0), (-1,2))
```

[image: Sage demo]

Here the addition sign is simply superposition of plots, not addition of vectors. Of course, Sage can add the components too.

---

Alternatively you could try an applet such as [this one](http://canu.ucalgary.ca/map/content/vectors/basic/simulate/2/), but the ones I saw were either rudimentary, or emphasized geometric manipulations over the numerical values of components. Not to mention that Java is evil.

Comment: Instead of sagenb, you can also use the [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com)

Comment: Or now [Sage Cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org)